# Vertex color value has weird offset in value when assigned from script

Tags: python, scripting, properties

What might explain this difference in values?

```
mesh.vertex_colors.active.data[loop_index].color[3] = colorItem.alpha
print(str(colorItem.alpha) + " / " + str(mesh.vertex_colors.active.data[loop_index].color[3]))
```

outputs 
0.03125 / 0.0313725508749485

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the blender sources, the colors seem to get rounded.

```
static void rna_MeshLoopColor_color_set(PointerRNA *ptr, const float *values)
{
  MLoopCol *mlcol = (MLoopCol *)ptr->data;

  mlcol->r = round_fl_to_uchar_clamp(values[0] * 255.0f);
  mlcol->g = round_fl_to_uchar_clamp(values[1] * 255.0f);
  mlcol->b = round_fl_to_uchar_clamp(values[2] * 255.0f);
  mlcol->a = round_fl_to_uchar_clamp(values[3] * 255.0f);
}
```